# django/selenium testing: how to debug a segmentation fault?

Tags: django, selenium

When running django tests using `StaticLiveServerTestCase` and selenium, I encounter occasional segmentation faults.

These crashes seem completely random: I could run the same test 10 or 20 times without changes and the segmentation fault will happen only 1 or 2 times and at seemingly random points in the test. The information I get back from the crash is also essentially nothing: `segmentation fault (core dumped) python manage.py test`.

I am wondering is there anyway to find out why this is happening? In other words, how do we debug crashes during python tests?

I tried `python -m pdb manage.py test`, but that does not allow the tests to run (it stops at the first import statement).

I have also tried

Updating all python packages. I am using python 2 in a virtualenv and have all packages completely up to date.

Updating my OS. I am using arch linux and am completely up to date.

Tried this on different computers. Same thing. Though am I just using arch linux on all computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an **SQLite backend** for testing / DEBUG, there is a known issue in Django.  I was able to resolve it with my steps provided at:  https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24080#comment:32

Keep in mind, these steps were performed on **Ubuntu Server 12.04**, opposed to your Arch Linux distro, but I'm sure you can adapted the following steps to upgrade to the latest and greatest SQLite3:

```
$ wget https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-autoconf-3081101.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz sqlite-autoconf-3081101.tar.gz
$ cd sqlite-autoconf-3081101
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
$ make
$ make install
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7 python2.7-minimal python2.7-dev python2.7-dbg
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worke for me.
However, upgrading sqlite to the latest version 3.14 did. No segmentation faults were encountered after the upgrade.
I downloaded the source code and compiled and installed according to the docs:

```
wget https://www.sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-autoconf-3140000.tar.gz
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then ran my unit tests. Everything worked from there!